# How to read a Gradle program from C#

Tags: c#, parsing, groovy, gradle

My company uses gradle to manage our builds. I want to write a tool in C# to help me do some testing and I'd like to get some of the configuration information that is embedded in the gradle script. I can treat the script as simple text and dig through it with regex, but I wondered if there way to have my C# program make sense of the gradle program a little more intelligently. For example, would a gradle lexer/parser written in C# provide the insight I want? Does such a thing exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Parsing build scripts yourself (regex/lexer/parser/etc.) is a dead end. It will only ever work in simple cases, and then it will be brittle. Instead, I'd go for one of the following:

- Get access to the information that you are after by writing (in the JVM language of your choice) a Gradle plugin, or a program that makes use of the Gradle tooling API. (Note: The tooling API only gives access to some of the information contained in a build script.)
- Refactor your Gradle builds to keep the information that you are after in an external data format (e.g. `gradle.properties` or a JSON file), and parse that.